# Admob ads showing in emulator but not in real device

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated admob in my app but the ads showed up in emulator but when i tried in real device it's not showing up. For integration i have added below code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Google Play service -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<!-- Ad activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Then in my activity's layout i have added below Linearlayout to load the ad in it :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Then in activity i have written below java code for integration :

```
/* The view to show the ad. */
private AdView adView;
/* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "My_admob_key";
// Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(MainMenu.this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
// until the ad is loaded.
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_banner);
layout.addView(adView);
// Initiate a generic request.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
// Load the adView with the ad request.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
layout.bringToFront();
```

Any help would be appreciated why ads are not showing up!!!! Also you can point to any good tuto for integrating admob will also help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Set device id for AdView.

Comment: for every device how i can add device id!!!!

Comment: you have to set your own device id not for all devices.

Comment: then will it work on every device!!!!!!

Comment: Don't u think if i will add my device id then it will work for my device only? plz correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No. nothing like that way. because i m using same way.

Comment: Can u plz write a example code here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the extras as well

```
 AdMobExtras extras = new AdMobExtras(bundle);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
 .addNetworkExtras(extras).build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: added..still same not able to load in device.

Comment: Can you send what the logcat says when you run your app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed adding `Test device` or added wrong ID, same thing happened with me as till I noticed in the Logcat this alert;

> 04-22 10:04:04.887 I/Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("6612F2AEECD2A4ADBD699CFC349AB01A") to
>   get test ads on this device.

Once I added it, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were an issue with the size of the view.
So I debugged the app in Android Studio and found the right hint in the Android Monitor Tab:

```
 Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x150 dp, but only has 318x0 dp.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues when I was working on changing the targetSDKversion.
I was using a Galaxy S7 phone to test.
I manged to get it working by allocating more space for the adview.
For ads to show up, tried making the view 3:1 with

```
android:layout_weight="3" for upper activity (75%)
android:layout_weight="1" for adView activity (25%)
android:layout_height="0dp"
```