# Android Admob ads working only before publishing application

Tags: android, admob

my application was recently removed from google play, after submitting it again I noticed I don't earn nothing from Admob, therefore I tried running the application on my test devices, in everyone of them I got the Test ad working great but then when I tried to use my friends phones to check if they can see the ad(downloaded real app from google play), I couldn't see the ads, so the ads aren't working for me now. here is my code:

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Activity**:

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR")
        .addTestDevice("207B846CF80A463F4B3150638CF7D2D0")
        .addTestDevice("0C3A7B25110E565DF33D48DCFE71ED05")
        .addTestDevice("49C6ED95F28B7F4413E2F118505A8B5B")
        .addTestDevice("74049DAA476D3FA230CF6FDD6D35CDCC")
        .build();
mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

**Androidmanifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="clash.davidbalas.com.deckrandomizer_clashroyale">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/images"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".main2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main4"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Admob recently integrated with firebase, I must change my code in app in order for it to work?

*Logcat:*

```
07-08 20:03:33.481 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-08 20:03:33.481 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("207B846CF80A463F4B3150638CF7D2D0") to get test ads on this device.
07-08 20:03:33.541 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-08 20:03:33.541 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-08 20:03:33.541 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("207B846CF80A463F4B3150638CF7D2D0") to get test ads on this device.
07-08 20:03:33.721 22018-22029/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
07-08 20:03:33.721 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
07-08 20:03:33.751 22018-22210/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
07-08 20:03:33.751 22018-22018/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192755/admob-ads-showing-in-emulator-but-not-in-real-device

Comment: @BR89 Why? my ads does show up,  I see the test ads but they don't show up after publishing the application, it's different.

Comment: @string/banner_ad_unit_id points to a valid unit_id, right?

Comment: Another point is that "REAL" ads will be displayed only in devices which were not included in addTestDevice()... If you are testing in same device, try to test in another one.

Comment: @GuilhermeP I tried to test in in devices are not included in addTestDevice(), and also yes, its a valid unit_id.. I am now trying to add interstitial ads too, I will update if it works.

Comment: Try to check the logcat if possible... filter by "Ads"... Ads usually prints logs... so, you will be able to see why is failling... then, update the question if the logcat error

Comment: @GuilhermeP trying to add interstitial ads give me an error "Error:(33, 5) error: cannot find symbol class InterstitialAd" , maybe something is not compiled correctly? I updated recently my google play services, build tools etc..

Comment: @GuilhermeP My bad, it wasn't asking to import classes. I will try to update soon.

Comment: Also  try keep your current code... it seems ok... then, reproduce the issue and check the logcat

Comment: @GuilhermeP Okay so after checking, when I try to run on a device is not on test devices, I get in logcat a warning I need to use addTestDevice() and loading ad is failed... and when I add it to test devices, it works fine as test ad, now I send a new version to production but I guess the ads will not work there neither..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116827/discussion-between-guilherme-p-and-davidbalas1).

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Hi David... Logcat will always display a warning to add the device in a testDevice list.. is normal... don't worry... Share the whole logcat (filtered by "Ads") in the question

Comment: @GuilhermeP Added, also I am available on chat now.